# How to pass data from father to son Component in a *ngFor Angular structure

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor

I'm learning Angular X and I try to pass some data from father to son component in a *ngFor structure.

This is my code I tried up to now

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-row',
  templateUrl: '<div class="rowTime " *ngFor="let row of rows">
                   <app-segment  [row]="row"> </app-segment>
                </div>',
  styleUrls: ['./row.component.css']
})
export class RowComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('segments') segments:SegmentComponent;
  rows = [{hour:"00:00"},{hour:"00:30"},{hour:"01:00"},{hour:"01:30"}]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

------------------------------------------------
@Component({
  selector: 'app-segment',
  templateUrl: '<div class="row border-top border-left border-botton ">
                   <div class="segmentHour">{{row}} </div>
               </div>',
  styleUrls: ['./segment.component.css']
})
export class SegmentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() row:string 

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

My aim is to pass the "row" value in every cicle of *ngFor to the "segment" Component, and to show it in it.

Up to now I've obtained this:

```
[object Object] aaaaa  bbbbb
[object Object] aaaaa  bbbbb
[object Object] aaaaa  bbbbb
[object Object] aaaaa  bbbbb
```

And I,d like to obtain that:

```
00:00 aaaaa  bbbbb
00:30 aaaaa  bbbbb
01:00 aaaaa  bbbbb
01:30 aaaaa  bbbbb
```

Comment: Try `{{row.hour}}` in `app-segment` component

Answer (score 2):

What you have done so far is correct. The reason why you are getting `[object Object]` is that the `row` that you have passed to the child is an object. You can either use a json pipe: `{{row | json}}` to view the complete object or print a property of `row`: `{{row.hour}}`

Answer (score 0):

replace binding {{row}} with {{row.hour}} will display hour value as expected